# Deriving Schwarzian Action in SYK Theory

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, physics, conformal-geometry, conformal-field-theory

I am trying to derive the Schwarzian action for the $q=4$ SYK model following ["An introduction to the SYK model"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03334) by V. Rosenhaus. I understand that we have the solution
$$G(\tau_1, \tau_2) =  \frac{b {\rm sgn}(\tau_1-\tau_2)}{ J ^{2\Delta}} \frac{f^\prime (\tau_1) ^\Delta f^\prime(\tau_2)^\Delta}{\vert f(\tau_1)-f(\tau_2)\vert^{2\Delta}} .\tag{3.4}$$
My problem is deriving the expansion of $G$. Supposedly, we change coordinates from $(\tau_1, \tau_2)$ to $(\tau_+, \tau_-)$ where $\tau_+= \frac{\tau_1+\tau_2}{2}$ and $\tau_-=\tau_1-\tau_2$. Taylor expand around $\tau_+$
$$G(\tau_1, \tau_2) = \frac{b {\rm sgn}(\tau_1-\tau_2)}{ \vert J (\tau_1-\tau_2) \vert^{2\Delta}} \left(1+ \frac{\Delta}{6} (\tau_1-\tau_2)^2 {\rm Sch}(f(\tau_+), \tau_+)+ O(\tau_1-\tau_2)^3 \right) .\tag{3.5}$$
It would be appreciated if someone could help show how this expansion is done or point to a resource where this has been detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Define
   $$ \tau~:=~\tau_+~:=~\frac{\tau_1+\tau_2}{2}, $$
   $$ 2\delta~:=~\tau_{12}~:=~\tau_1-\tau_2, $$
   and the [Schwarzian derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative) $${\rm Sch}(f(\tau),\tau)~:=~\frac{f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\tau)}{f^{\prime}(\tau)}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\tau)}{f^{\prime}(\tau)}\right)^2.$$
2. Then
   $$\begin{align}
   \tau_{12}^2&\frac{f^{\prime}(\tau_1)f^{\prime}(\tau_2)}{[f(\tau_1)-f(\tau_2)]^2}~=~\ldots\cr
   ~=~&\delta^2\frac{[f^{\prime}(\tau)+\delta f^{\prime\prime}(\tau)+\frac{\delta^2}{2} f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\tau)+O(\delta^3)][f^{\prime}(\tau)-\delta f^{\prime\prime}(\tau)+\frac{\delta^2}{2} f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\tau)+O(\delta^3)]}{[\delta f^{\prime}(\tau)+\frac{\delta^3}{6} f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\tau)+O(\delta^5)]^2}\cr
   ~=~&\frac{[f^{\prime}(\tau)+\frac{\delta^2}{2} f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\tau)]^2-[\delta f^{\prime\prime}(\tau)]^2+O(\delta^3)}{[f^{\prime}(\tau)+\frac{\delta^2}{6} f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\tau)+O(\delta^4)]^2}\cr
   ~=~&\frac{f^{\prime}(\tau)^2+\delta^2 f^{\prime}(\tau)f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\tau)-\delta^2 f^{\prime\prime}(\tau)^2+O(\delta^3)}{f^{\prime}(\tau)^2+\frac{\delta^2}{3} f^{\prime}(\tau)f^{\prime\prime\prime}(\tau)+O(\delta^4)}\cr
   ~=~&\ldots~=~1+\frac{2\delta^2}{3}{\rm Sch}(f(\tau),\tau))+O(\delta^3)\cr
   ~=~&1+\frac{\tau_{12}^2}{6}{\rm Sch}(f(\tau),\tau)+O(\tau_{12}^3)
   \end{align}. $$
3. Finally consider the $\Delta$'th power to derive eq. (3.5).

References:

1. V. Rosenhaus, *An intro to SYK,* [arXiv:1807.03334](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03334); eqs. (3.4)-(3.5).